# Connecting IR LED to a ESP32

Tags: transistors, led, esp32

I'm trying to connect this module to an ESP32 controller.

[image]

ESP32's GPIO is rated at 3.3 V, 20 mA per pin. The IR LED (as far as I understand) requires 100 mA, so I need a transistor to power it.

I have a power supply with output characteristics: 4.8 V=8.5 V, 600mAh.
I want to connect this power supply to the ESP32 and in parallel to the transmitter module through a transistor controlled by the ESP32's pin. The problem: I don't know a lot about transistors characteristics and electronics in general.

What transistors can I use for this task? I have these: C1815Y, C8550, S9014C, C8050D, D882P, and B772P. Would any of them would OK? Should I use resistors? The transmitter module has some, as far as I can see.

Comment: You need to supply a datasheet for the device - preferably one with a schematic). (An Amazon ad is not a datasheet.) It has a DAT (data?) pin which suggests that there is a transistor onboard to do the switching but it's not on the side we can see.

Comment: Did you try to search how this particular module gets interfaced with other popular DIY platforms like Arduino or RRi? Where did you get that it requires 100mA to operate?

Comment: Maybe you should start with this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qRNJhU1OLM

Comment: @Transistor I have a link to the page of the product: https://aliexpress.com/item/1005003804455377.html?sku_id=12000027223801982
As far as I understand, it doesn't have a transistor and VCC pin on this board isn't used at all. There is nothing on the another side.

Comment: @Ale..chenski I read that this is a usual requirement for IR leds. The device page doesn't have any information about amps.

Comment: There's no point in me looking at the AliExpress site as they don't give datasheets either.

Comment: @Transistor I agree. It's a problem. All I see is an IR LED, 2 resistors on a GND line, and 1 LED on a DAT line. No transistors.

Comment: @Transistor it looks like it is HX-53 module. At least, it has same resistors, 1 LED on a DAT line and dummy VCC pin.